# Prove that following 3-CNF is SAT

Tags: satisfiability, 3-sat

> Let $\phi$ be a 3-CNF expression with the properties
>
> 1. Every variable can be used at most 3 times
> 2. No Variable can be used twice in a term
>
> Show that you can always choose the truth-value of the variables such that $\phi$ is true.

My attempt was to express this problem as a bipartite graph and then use Hall's theorem.

It's pretty easy to see, that the number of terms must be less than or equal to the number of variables. Because each term needs $3$ different variables, so in the "worst case" (to achieve max. amount of terms) those $3$ variables are used   $3$ times. But then we have $3$ variables and $3$ terms. Otherwise, if these variables are used less than $3$ times, we need additional variables therefore $\#\text{ terms}\leq \#\text{ variables}$

Next step was to make the problem a bipartite graph.
[image]

This picture should show the idea (I know it's not 3-CNF, please disregard the $t$ in the middle term)

As you can see, every term has exactly $3$ connections to variables. Like discussed earlier, the minimum amount of variables, that a union of three (not necessarily different) terms $t_1\cup t_2 \cup t_3$ can have, is $3$. For 6 terms $t_1\cup t_2 \cup t_3\cup t_4 \cup t_5\cup t_6$ it's $6$ and so on.

This means every subset $T=\{t_1,...,t_n\}$ with terms of $\phi$ has a neighborhood (amount of variables) greater or equal to $\#T$. That satisfies Hall's condition and by Hall's theorem we have a matching of size $\#T$.

I think this basically means that I can choose a different "representative variable" for every term, right? By that I mean a variable whose truth value is chosen such that it's designated term is true.

If I choose every representative variable to satisfy it's designated term, then $\phi$ is satisfiable, right?

For instance, in the picture above, $p$ is the rep. variable of the 1st term, $s$ of the 2nd term and $q$ of the 3rd term. So $(\neg p, \neg s, q)$ would make the formula sat.

Did I miss anything? Is there something to add? I'd like to hear your opinion.

Comment: Do you require this condition: "No Variable can be used twice in a term" to prove the statement?

Comment: I guess you're right. Don't really need that condition but I think it's easier to look at it with that.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.